# System.UnauthorizedAccessException on RHEL4/Mono x86_64

Tags: linux, mono, permissions, mod-mono

I am using mod_mono 2.4.2.3 and Apache 2 to host a web application. This application tries to generate a temp image on its temp folder, but it gives me this error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/opt/franquia/hlrgw/Frontend/tmp/ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ZedGraphWeb1f3c01ca1-bb4f-4b5b-9063-eebf0bb3281b.png" is denied. at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare) at ZedGraph.Web.ZedGraphWeb.Render (System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter output) [0x00000]
```

This folder has the "apache" user/group owner, the same user configured to run apache and mod_mono. I even set 666 permissions for debugging purposes, but it still doesn't work.

The only catch is that this folder is being synchronized with other server via rsync (the web application works fine there). This is the line used:

```
*/5 * * * * rsync  -vuatpog --delete root@rtclp02:/opt/franquia/hlrgw /opt/franquia/
```

Both servers have the same users, uids and groups. I don't know what to do anymore :(

Comment: I've learned sometime that apache only likes those folders where it can list+read the parent-folders. Means if you have /foo/bar/fu and 'fu' is the folder apache accesses, it also wants to be able to read & list 'foo' and 'bar'.

Answer (score 0):

mod-mono-server2, spawned by mod-mono, runs as the *wwwrun* (or *apache*) user. That folder needs to be writeable for this user (and/or whatever group apache is running under) in order for that application to work.